# Recursion, iteration, and ...?

Tags: terminology, recursion, loops, control-structures

Here are three common code structures that apply a function multiple times:

```
foo(x) {
    if basecase(x) return k else return foo(g(x))
}
```

uses recursion.

```
for i in 0..10 {
    n *= bar(i)
}
```

uses iteration.

```
baz(baz(baz(baz(quux))))
```

uses...?

In mathematics it'd be considered iteration, but mathematics doesn't generally concern itself with `for` and `while` loops, which are what people associate with the term in programming. How do programmers tersely and unambiguously refer to the third construct?

Comment: I have never seen a special name for this construct. It is not analogous to iteration or recursion, as it is a hard-coded statement which never checks any conditions, and always runs N times (where N is the number of invocations you've physically written into the code). The point of iteration and recursion is typically to execute a set of steps some _arbitrary_ number of times, based on a set of inputs and a condition that is evaluated on each invocation.

Comment: Nesting? That's just multiple nested function calls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The term you're looking is for is [**function composition**](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition), although I'm not sure if there's a more specific term for the special case of a function composed with itself.

Comment: Maybe __iterated function__? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function

Comment: After all, also `for` and `while` loops are nothing else but iterated functions in disguise.